# How to select records by date without using CAST?

Tags: sql, delphi

On my filter form i have two edit and they are give the result like this "01.12.2014"...

This is the turkish standard and format is dd.mm.yyyy

In the code section i have controlled them and convert the value with formatdatetime. and create aa select sql.

```
  if edtTar1.Value>0 then tar1:=FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd',edtTar1.Value);
  if edtTar2.Value>0 then tar2:=FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd',edtTar2.Value);

  tarsart := ' and ( Convert(nvarchar(8), Sip_Tarih, 112) >= Convert(nvarchar(8), cast('+QuotedStr(tar1)+' as datetime), 112) '+
  ' and Convert(nvarchar(8), Sip_Tarih, 112) <= Convert(nvarchar(8), cast('+QuotedStr(tar2)+' as datetime), 112)) ' ;
```

Tar1 and Tar2 are string values. Sip_tarih is datetime field.

My question is can i get the record by date without using CAST in my SQL?

Regards

Comment: You're looking for the wrong solution. Use date-time controls, and use parameterized queries. Then you don't have to cast, and you don't have to concern yourself with the user's preferred date format. (Just because your users are Turkish and working in Turkey doesn't necessarily mean they'll all be using the common Turkish date format.) In other words, your entire problem just goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should work

```
tarsart := ' and Sip_Tarih >= cast('+QuotedStr(tar1)+' as datetime)) '+
' and Sip_Tarih <= cast('+QuotedStr(tar2)+' as datetime)) ' ;
```

And depending on your SQL settings, this might work too

```
tarsart := ' and Sip_Tarih >= '+QuotedStr(tar1)+
' and Sip_Tarih <= '+QuotedStr(tar2) ;
```

Comment: "And depending on your SQL settings,"

Can u explain a little more that ?

Comment: tarsart := ' and Sip_Tarih >= '+QuotedStr(tar1)+
' and Sip_Tarih <= '+QuotedStr(tar2) ;

Worked... Thanks... I think other anwers are ok too but i just want to remove cast for speed purposes.

Comment: If your SQL server recognizes a string formated as yyyymmdd as a date by default you don't need to cast to DateTime.  Alternatively, you could find out what date format SQL is using by default and pass your strings as that format to avoid that additional cast.

@afrazier in that you should be trying to use a parameterized query to avoid risk of SQL injection, though risk is pretty low in this case since you are converting dates to strings to append to your query, but it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: As you said, "Alternatively, you could find out what date format SQL is using by default and pass your strings as that format to avoid that additional cast." 

I want to learn that how we can do it.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do this easily by eliminating all the extra `Convert` statements:

```
tarsart := ' and (Sip_Tarih >= cast('+QuotedStr(tar1)+' as datetime) '+
' and Sip_Tarih <= cast('+QuotedStr(tar2)+' as datetime)) ';
```

Now, this said, it would also be a good idea for you to look into paramaterized SQL queries.  Not only does it eliminate the need to cast strings in your SQL, but it also protects your application from SQL Injection.  Depending on the SQL server, it may also improve performance since compiled queries can be reused with different parameters.

Comment: I'm currently trying the minimise use tadoquery count. So im using same queries for more than one form. Because of that i think using parameters is not suitable at this step.

Comment: You can still reuse `TADOQuery` objects by setting the SQL and then doing the parameter binding at runtime.  That allows for more gains by extracting the dynamic SQL into constants and reducing string manipulation in code.

Comment: Would +1 for mentioning params, but -1 for not showing them

Answer (score 5):

Use a parameterized SQL query instead and let the database handle the date/time formatting for you, and get rid of the unnecessary conversions:

```
tarsart := ' and (Sip_Tarih >= :ptar1) and (Sip_Tarih <= :ptar2) ' ;
```

```
Query.SQL.Text := ... + tarsart + ...;
Query.ParamByName('ptar1').AsDateTime := edtTar1.Value;
Query.ParamByName('ptar2').AsDateTime := edtTar2.Value;
```